# What are the different event handlers got for fb-send button

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use fb-javascriptSDK.
At some place i need to show a send button - to send a message to fb friends from within the website.

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.example.com"></div>
```

Here I have few questions:
1) How to pre-fill the message text-area with some content, by default? (I wanted to put some html content)
2) currently if i include the above html, the f-send button is created and if user clicks on that button, a popup is coming. But can i have an event when the user first clicks on f-send button? ( NOT the "send" submit button inside the popup )
3) With FB.Event.Subscribe - message.send, I have an event handler after the message has been posted. But is there a way to attach an event before posting the message?

Please clarify my doubts...

Regards,
SuryaPavan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No event is triggered until the message is sent
- You cannot prefill the message text.
- You cannot use HTML in the message text